# Draw the graph $f(x)=|3-2x|-x$

Tags: geometry, functions

I am trying to draw the graph of $f(x)=|3-2x|-x$. We can notice $3-2x=0$ when $x=\dfrac32$. So $$f(x)=\begin{cases}(3-2x)-x=3-3x,x\ge\dfrac32\\-(3-2x)-x=x-3,x<\dfrac32\end{cases}$$ So $y_1=3-3x$ and I am using the points $A\left(\dfrac32;-\dfrac32\right)$ and $B\left(2;-3\right)$; and $y_2=x-3$ with the points $A$ and $C\left(0;-3\right)$. I think that the graph should be only the angle which points downwards (the purple angle), not upwards as it's supposed to be. Because we should construct the ray $AB$ not $BA$ because we want $x \ge \dfrac32$
[image]

Comment: You have defined $f(x)$ incorrectly. For $x \geq 3/2$, it should be $ - (3-2x) - x$ and for $x \lt 3/2$, it should be $(3-2x)-x$

Comment: As for the geometrical interpretation, function $x\mapsto 3-3x$ is decreasing, and $x\mapsto x-3$ is increasing. Therefore you can pick corresponding ray in $(-\infty,\frac{3}{2})$ and $(\frac{3}{2},\inf)$ without considering any points on the plane.